# Multiple inhertinace

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have some classes having a .NET control:

```
Class MyTextBox : Inherits MyControl
    Control As TextBox
```

I would like to use the inheritance instead of having a variable containing the .NET control:

```
Class MyTextBox : Inherits TextBox
```

Since multiple inheritance is not supported in .NET, is there a way for me to inherit from MyControl class AND having all the implementation of the .NET TextBox?

```
Class MyControl : Inherits Control

Class MyTextBox : Inherits MyControl
    (all methods, property, events of the TextBox class)
```

So I can have all the attributes/operations of the TextBoxes, ComboBoxes and whatever in my subclasses plus my personal one and generic atts/ops on my MyControl class inherited from the subones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, .NET (and most modern languages and OOP environments) won't support multi-inheritance - and it is a good design decision -.

Not a workaround but the actual solution is *wrapping*.

If you want your control to be `MyControl` and also `TextBox` there're other ways of getting such relationship: *interfaces*.

Your specialized `TextBox` should inherit the .NET built-in `TextBox` control class and implement `IMyControl` interface.

The functionality that the `SpecializedTextBox` must implement can be implemented in a separate class and use its members in the implementation of `IMyControl` on `SpecializedTextBox`.

I'm going to write down a sample in C#, but it should be enough for you as you're VB.NET developer and the solution is language-neutral:

```
public interface IMyControl 
{
     void Do();
}

public class SpecializedTextBox : TextBox, IMyControl
{
     private readonly MyControlExtension _extension = new MyControlExtension(this);

     public MyControlExtension Extension 
     {
          get { return _extension; }
     }

     public void Do()
     {
          Extension.Do();
     }
}

public class MyControlExtension
{
    public MyControlExtension(Control wrappedControl)
    {
         _wrappedControl = wrappedControl;
    }

    private readonly Control _wrappedControl;

    public Control WrappedControl { get { return _wrapedControl; } }

    public void Do() 
    {
         // Do some stuff with the WrappedControl property contained control

    } 
}
```

Now `SpecializedTextBox` control have both `IMyControl` and `TextBox` members.

As far as I know, this will be enough to *simulate* multi-inheritance, as a class can implement one or more interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the following article

- [Simulated Multiple Inheritance Pattern for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C)